# (Query SQL) Limitar a quantidade de linhas de um select com inner join e where in

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho 3 tabelas, products, category, product_categories, esta ultima foi criada pq a relação de produto e categoria é n para n. Eu tenho um select que me retorna todos os produtos de todas as categorias, mas eu queria que me retornasse apenas 10 produtos de cada categoria

Este é meu select:

`select "products".*, "product_categories"."idCategory" as "idCategory" 
from "products" 
inner join "product_categories" on "products"."id" = "product_categories"."idProduct" 
where "product_categories"."idCategory" in (5,4,10,7)`

Se o `limit` for colocado no fim da query é retornado apenas os 10 primeiros produtos e suas respectivas categorias

E também já pensei em fazer diversas consultas, uma para cada categoria, mas isso seria muito demorado comparado ao que tenho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível de utilizar o **ROW_NUMBER** para estabelecer um índice para a categoria, assim, com o **PATITION BY**, toda vez que for uma categoria nova, ele reinicia o índice.

Coloque isto como uma subselect e no **WHERE** da consulta de fora coloque filtrando a quantidade.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."IDCATEGORY" ORDER BY "PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."IDCATEGORY") AS INDICE,
    "PRODUCTS".*, 
    "PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."IDCATEGORY" AS "IDCATEGORY" 
    FROM "PRODUCTS"
    INNER JOIN "PRODUCT_CATEGORIES" ON "PRODUCTS"."ID" = "PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."IDPRODUCT" 
    WHERE "PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."IDCATEGORY" IN (5,4,10,7)
) AS X
WHERE X.INDICE <= 10
```

Comment: Só por curiosidade, como seria isso para MS SQL SERVER?

Comment: Algo assim:
CREATE TABLE TEST (
 ID VARCHAR(100),
 PRODUTO VARCHAR(100),
 CATEGORIA VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (1, 'MAÇA', 'FRUTA')
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (2, 'PERA', 'FRUTA')
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (3, 'CENOURA', 'VEG')
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (4, 'BETERRABA', 'VEG')
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (5, 'BANANA', 'FRUTA')
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (6, 'ABOBORA', 'VEG')

SELECT CATEGORIA, PRODUTO
FROM
(
 SELECT
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CATEGORIA ORDER BY CATEGORIA) AS QTD,
 PRODUTO, CATEGORIA
 FROM TEST
 GROUP BY CATEGORIA, PRODUTO
) AS X
WHERE QTD <= 2

Comment: Interessante,  muito obrigado.

Comment: Coloquei no JS Fidle para ficar formatado: https://jsfiddle.net/n253oLda/

Comment: Testei aqui em um banco local, funciona direitinho, nunca precisei de algo do tipo, mas se um dia precisar já lhe agradeço

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!!! E o melhor é que esta query demora tanto quanto a outra que eu estava utilizando, muito bom

Answer (score 1):

Compromete um pouco o tempo da requisição, mas creio que resolva seu problema ao usar uma subquery

```
select "products".*, "product_categories"."idCategory" as "idCategory" 
from "products" inner join "product_categories" 
on "products"."id" = 
    (SELECT "product_categories"."idProduct" 
    FROM 'product_categories' 
    where "product_categories"."idCategory" in (5,4,10,7) LIMIT 10)
```

Comment: só por curiosidade, como seria isso para MS SQL SERVER?

Comment: Tentei utilizar o código, mas deu erro (ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression), só funciona se colocar o limit como 1 e ainda assim retorna varias linhas com o mesmo produto, então acredito que a sua query não me retornaria 10 produtos para cada categoria