# Como selecionar apenas a primeira linha do row_number

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT SA.RA, PP.NOME, SC.COMPLEMENTO, SPL.ANO, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SA.RA ORDER BY SPL.ANO ASC) 
    AS U_PERLET
```

Estou fazendo este select, está retornando todos os dados com uma contagem, a contagem é feita por cada RA e ordenada por ano.
O que eu precisava é mostrar apenas o ultimo ano registrado, pois existem varios. Estou colocando a ROW_NUMBER e colocando por ondem, sendo que o ultimo ano sempre vai ser o maior numero desta contagem descrita acima. Alguma dica?

Comment: Usar `SELECT TOP 1` resolve seu problema? Sua pergunta e o resultado esperado não está muito claro.

Comment: @gmsantos editei a pergunta, está mais claro??

Comment: Veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/233166/selecionar-primeiro-registro-dentro-de-uma-segmenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-sql-server/233178#233178

Comment: @anonimo criar um subquery então? deu certo! obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
MAX(X.U_PERLET) AS ANO,
X.RA,
X.NOME,
[...]

FROM
(
    SELECT 
    SA.RA, 
    PP.NOME, 
    SC.COMPLEMENTO, 
    SPL.ANO, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SA.RA ORDER BY SPL.ANO ASC) AS U_PERLET

    FROM [...]

) AS X
GROUP BY
    X.RA,
    X.NOME,
    [...]
```

OU

```
SELECT
SA.RA, 
PP.NOME, 
SC.COMPLEMENTO, 
SPL.ANO, 
MAX(SPL.ANO) AS U_PERLET

FROM [...]

GROUP BY 
    SA.RA, 
    PP.NOME, 
    SC.COMPLEMENTO, 
    SPL.ANO
```

Esta resposta também poderá te ajudar:

[(Query SQL) Limitar a quantidade de linhas de um select com inner join e where in](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/432437/query-sql-limitar-a-quantidade-de-linhas-de-um-select-com-inner-join-e-where-i/432445#432445)